# Firebase messaging onMessage only available in a window

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging in my project to send and receive push notifications. I can receive push notifications, but I am not able to get the notification events to work. Specifically, I want to get the `onMessage` event to work, but for some reason, it gives me this error:

> Messaging: This method is available in a Window context.
>   (messaging/only-available-in-window).

This is my service-worker for messaging:

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-messaging.js')

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: 'XXXXXXXX'
})

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging()
// messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
//   console.log(payload)
// })
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  // Messages received. Either because the
  // app is running in the foreground, or
  // because the notification was clicked.
  // `payload` will contain your data.
  console.log('Message received. ', payload)
})
```

I also tried to add the function to my Vue component, but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `onMessage` callback should not be registered from within a service worker. In the service worker you should use (see [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_background)):

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // ...
});
```

I can confirm that this is currently working for me. Note that this will be triggered only when your app is in the **background**, and you are sending **data messages**. If you are sending *notifications*, then the SDK will handle displaying of the message automatically and your `setBackgroundMessageHandler` callback will not be triggered. Even if you send a payload with both *data* and *notification* content, the SDK will intervene.

If you want to react to messages outside of a service worker, note that the tab containing your website should be in the foreground. Then the following code should work (the same as you had it):

```
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // ...
});
```

I have the above snippet in my Vue component (although I am using Vue 3), and I am not getting an error<s>, but the callback is not getting triggered either. Perhaps you will have better luck</s>. This should be triggered for any kind of message, be it *data*, *notification*, or both.

Also note the table at the top of the linked doc to get an understanding of when which callback will be triggered.

**Edit**: Apparently the `onMessage` callback will not be triggered when your Firebase JS SDK that you installed via npm/Yarn is not the same version as the one you are importing from the service worker. For example, mine from npm was version 7.2.3 and the one imported by the service worker was 6.3.4. After updating the service worker with 7.2.3, the `onMessage` callback was being triggered while the app is in the foreground. [Thanks to ErAz7](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2210#issuecomment-536466335)!

Comment: you saved my half of life. after facing this issue over 12 hours i got my life back. what i was facing is version issue it really sucks

Comment: Where are you using the below call ? 

```
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // ...
});
```

I am trying to call this in the created hook but it says messaging is undefined.

Comment: This here paints a full picture:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824118/firebase-cloud-messaging-foreground-notification-not-working-in-vue/74116026#74116026