# Firebase Cloud Messaging foreground notification not working in Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working on integrating FCM in my Vue PWA app. So far I've managed to get the background notification working, but handling notifications when the app's on the foreground doesn't work. Here's my code.

#### `src/App.vue`

```js
import firebase from './plugins/firebase'

export default {
  // Other stuff here...

  methods: {
    prepareFcm () {
      var messaging = firebase.messaging()
      messaging.usePublicVapidKey(this.$store.state.fcm.vapidKey)
      messaging.getToken().then(async fcmToken => {
        this.$store.commit('fcm/setToken', fcmToken)
        messaging.onMessage(payload => {
          window.alert(payload)
        })
      }).catch(e => {
        this.$store.commit('toast/setError', 'An error occured to push notification.')
      })
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.prepareFcm()
  }
}
```

#### `public/firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-messaging.js')

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: '123456789'
})

const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  return self.registration.showNotification(payload)
})
```

#### `src/plugins/firebase.js`

```js
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/messaging'
// import other firebase stuff...

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '123456789',
  appId: '...'
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default firebase
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you try move the onMessage block  "messaging.onMessage(payload => {window.alert(payload)})" outside of the function after successfully get the FCM Token. I don't think this onMessage function need to put in the promise after getting FCM

Comment: I am having same issue please let me know if you happen to fix it

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution in another QA here in StackOverflow (which I can't find anymore for some reason).

Turns out you have to use Firebase API v7.8.0 instead of 5.5.6 like the docs said at the time. So those first two lines in `public/firebase-messaging-sw.js` should read like this instead:

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-messaging.js')
```

Comment: If someone could find that QA, feel free to edit my answer to include that link.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue i was faced. In my case firebase version in **"package.json"** and **"firebase-messaging-sw.js"** importScripts version was different. After set same version in **"firebase-messaging-sw.js"** importScripts which was in
**"package.json"**, my issue is resolved.

**Before change**

```
 **"package.json"**
 
 "firebase": "^8.2.1",
 
  **"firebase-messaging-sw.js"**

 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-app.js');
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

**After change**

```
 **"package.json"**

 "firebase": "^8.2.1",

 **"firebase-messaging-sw.js"**

 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js');
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the version on `package.json` (8.2.1) was different from the actual SDK_VERSION (8.0.1)

After changed service-workers with the same version worked..

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of issues setting firebase push notifications for Vue 3 (with Vite), and I had PWA support enabled with `vite-plugin-pwa`, so it felt like I was flying blind half the time. I was finally able to set up support for PWA, but then I ran into the following issues:

- I was getting notifications in the background (when my app was not in focus), but not in the foreground.
- When I did get notifications in the background, it appeared twice.

Here's my complete setup. I have the latest firebase as of this post (`9.12.1`)

```
// firebase-messaging-sw.js file in the public folder
   
importScripts(
      "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-app-compat.js"
    );
importScripts(
      "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
    );
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
// Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
  body: payload.notification.body,
  icon: "/icon.png",
};

self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

I've seen some posts online provide the `onBackgroundMessage` here in the service worker, but I experimented with commenting it out and it seemed to fix the issue of notifications appearing twice.

Next, is a `firebase.js` file with which I retrieve tokens and subsequently listen for foreground notifications.

```
// firebase.js in same location with main.js
    
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
    
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};
    
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default getMessaging(app);
```

And then in `main.js`

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import firebaseMessaging from "./firebase";

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.$messaging = firebaseMessaging; //register as a global property
```

And finally, in `App.vue` (or wherever you wish to get tokens and send to your serverside)...

```
import {getToken, onMessage} from "firebase/messaging";

export default {
  mounted() {
    getToken(this.$messaging, {
      vapidKey:
        "XXX-XXX",
    })
      .then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log("client token", currentToken);
          onMessage(this.$messaging, (payload) => {
            console.log("Message received. ", payload);
          });
          
          //send token to server-side
        } else {
          console.log(
            "No registration token available. Request permission to generate one"
          );
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token.", err);
      });
  }
}
```

Of course don't forget the `vapidKey`. Took a minute, but it worked perfectly.

For now, I am not offering any opinion as to what the foreground notification should look like, so I am merely logging the payload. But feel free to show it however you deem fit.